# Class variable type depending on another class variable's type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

```
class A:
    var_a: bool = False
    var_b: int | str  # str if var_a is True, else int


a = A()
a.var_a = True
a.var_b # should be str
```

How can I type this so that mypy knows var_b should be a string if var_a is True? Is this possible? Maybe with some clever usage of `Literal[True]` or `Literal[False]`?

Comment: The type you're looking for is called a [dependent pair](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/built-ins.html#the-type), and unfortunately Python's type system is nowhere near powerful enough to be able to describe dependent types.

Comment: So I guss, given `overload` and literals, as in the provided answer, Python does not support it out of the box, but it is far closer to that than "nowhere near powerful enough".

That said, everyone should always keep in mind that typing in Python is an _optional_ step executed prior to the program, and plain, old unit-testing should be used in cases like this - the annotation might just be `int | str`

Comment: Providing your intended use case would help us make a better suggestion. What if `a.var_b` has a non-integer string value, then you change `a.var_a = False`? What is supposed to happened to the value of `a.var_b`? Or should you really have two different classes altogether, one with a string-valued attribute, the other with an integer-valued attribute?

Comment: If you *can't* change `var_a` after `a` is initialized, then why not simply use two different classes `Aint` and `Astr` with appropriately typed `var_b` attributes in each?

Comment: One difficulty with using `Literal` in this context is that you can't exhaustively describe `bool` with `Literal`s because you can subclass `bool` arbitrarily. I can well believe using `Literal` in this way is antithetical to Python's OO emphasis.

Comment: @joel Exactly; `Literal` is meant to represent *actual literals*, not just specific values of a type.

Comment: @jsbueno agree.  Not only that but if your good-for-typing code is 3x more complicated and harder to read than the dumbed-down no typing version … read The Zen : *simple is better than complex*.  The requirement is clear enough in plain English, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Silvio Mayolo is right, this is a dependent pair, and it's not supported in Python. Here it is in [Idris](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#dependent-pairs). However, you're right that you can very vaguely approximate behaviour like this with `Literal` (and `overload`). That said, don't. This example is horrible in a number of ways.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Literal, Generic, overload

Bool = TypeVar("Bool", Literal[True], Literal[False])


class A(Generic[Bool]):
    @overload
    def __init__(self: A[Literal[True]], a: Literal[True], b: int): ...
    
    @overload
    def __init__(self: A[Literal[False]], a: Literal[False], b: str): ...

    def __init__(self, a: Literal[True, False], b: str | int):
        self._var_a = a
        self._var_b = b

    @property
    def var_a(self) -> Literal[True, False]:
        return self._var_a

    @overload
    def var_b(self: A[Literal[True]]) -> int: ...

    @overload
    def var_b(self: A[Literal[False]]) -> str: ...

    def var_b(self):
        return self._var_b

a = A(True, 0)
reveal_type(a.var_b())   # main.py:31: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

You may be able to massage this to work with your exact example through `property`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `var_a` at all. You can make `A` *generic*, and let its concrete type be set when you initialize it with an appropriate value for `var_b`,

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T', int, str)

class A(Generic[T]):
    var: T

    def __init__(self, x: T):
        self.var = x


a1 = A(5)  # OK, bind T to int
a2 = A("foo")  # OK, bind T to str
# a3 = A(3.195)  # ERROR, T cannot be bound to float

reveal_type(a1.var)  # builtins.int
reveal_type(a2.var)  # builtins.str
reveal_type(A)  # See below
reveal_type(a1)  # A[int]
reveal_type(a2)  # A[str]
```

The revealed type for `A` itself can be read roughly as "`A` maps type `T` to type A[T], as long as `T` is `str` or `int`.