# Type checking an optional attribute whose value is related to that of another attribute

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typechecking

I have a function which computes a `Result` and this computation can either be `success`ful or not. In case it was successful, some `data` that summarizes the result of the computation will be returned as well. In case it was unsuccessful, this data will be `None`. Now the problem is that even though I verify the status of the computation (`success`), the type checker (`mypy`) cannot infer the coupling between `success` and `data`. This is summarized by the following code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Result:
    success: bool
    data: Optional[int]  # This is not None if `success` is True.


def compute(inputs: str) -> Result:
    if inputs.startswith('!'):  # Oops, some condition that prevents the computation.
        return Result(success=False, data=None)
    return Result(success=True, data=len(inputs))


def check(inputs: str) -> bool:
    return (result := compute(inputs)).success and result.data > 2


assert check('123')
assert not check('12')
assert not check('!123')
```

Running `mypy` against this code gives the following error:

```
test.py:18: error: Unsupported operand types for < ("int" and "None")  [operator]
test.py:18: note: Left operand is of type "Optional[int]"
```

I considered the following solutions, but I'm not really happy with either of them. So, I'm wondering if there's a better way to solve this.

#### [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)

The function `check` could be modified to use `cast(int, result.data)` to enforce the logical relationship between `success` and `data`. However, having to resort to `cast` feels like a sign of something being wrong with the code (in this case, at least). Also, I would have to use `cast` each time this relationship is used in the code. It would be better to solve it in one place.

#### Check `result.data is not None`

In the above example, the relationship between `success` and `data` is quite simple: `success == data is not None`. So, I could remove the attribute `success` altogether and, instead, check for `result.data is not None`.

```py
def check(inputs: str) -> bool:
    return (result := compute(inputs)).data is not None and result.data > 2
```

While this works, the real use case is more complex and there are various data fields, e.g., `data_x`, `data_y`, and `data_z`. In this case, `success == all(d is not None for d in [data_x, data_y, data_z])`. Using this as a check is too verbose and so I would refactor it into a `property` of the `Result` class. For the above example this would be:

```py
@dataclass
class Result:
    data: Optional[int]

    @property
    def success(self) -> bool:
        return self.data is not None
```

However, when the `is not None` check is moved into a property, `mypy` cannot infer anymore that `result.data` really is not `None` when `result.success` is `True`.

Comment: I've given a long and involved answer. I like it, but if you don't feel like reading it, `TypeGuard` might help you

Comment: There is already an answer for the question how to type-annotate this solution, but consider also a completely different approach: raise `LookupError`  on failure and return `int` on success.

Comment: @zvone that's might be OK as a solution, but the question is clearly about static typing, and exceptions aren't typed

Comment: @joel that is why I offered it as a comment and not as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial question is extremely close to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75476855/5986907), but the overall question is not just about that, so here goes.

Here's one option of several.

The fact that you have `success == all(d is not None for d in [data_x, data_y, data_z])` in your general case suggests to me that what you really want is a simple `Result` type, and to compose them. There's a very well established pattern for this in Haskell/Rust etc, though it's usually called `Maybe` or `Option` there. In Python this would look like

```
@dataclass
class Success[T]:
    data: T

class Fail:
    pass

Result[T] = Success[T] | Fail
```

and you'd use it like so

```
def compute(inputs: str) -> Result[int]:
    if inputs.startswith('!'):  # Oops, some condition that prevents the computation.
        return Fail()
    return Success(len(inputs))
```

now it's not clear to me what role `check` would play here, as it depends on your needs. The simplest way you could do it is

```
def check(inputs: str) -> bool:
    match compute(inputs):
        case Success(x):
            return x > 2
        case Fail():
            return False
```

but you might find functions like

```
def is_success[T](r: Result[T]) -> bool:
    return isinstance(r, Success)

def map[T, U](result: Result[T], f: Callable[[T], U]) -> Result[U]:
    match result:
        case Success(x):
            return Success(f(x))
        case Fail:
            return Fail()
```

useful more generally, in which case you might do

```
def check(inputs: str) -> bool:
    return is_success(map(compute(inputs), lambda data: result.data > 2))
```

That's not very pretty, partly because I don't really know what `check` is for.

When you have multiple values, you could combine multiple functions with a *combinator* like

```
def map2[T, U, V](r0: Result[T], r1: Result[U], f: Callable[[T, U], V]) -> Result[V]:
    match (r0, r1):
        case (Success(x0), Success(x1)):
            return Success(f(x0, x1))
        case _:
            return Fail()

@dataclass
class TwoThings:
    data0: int
    data1: int

hopefully_two_things: Result[TwoThings] = map2(compute("foo"), compute("bar"), TwoThings)
```

Comment: also, apologies, there were a lot of typos

Comment: I like the approach, but it could be simplified. There is actually no need for `Fail` - `None` can do the job. The function can simply return `Success | None`.

Comment: @zvone that is true

Comment: @joel Indeed, implementing two different classes for `Success` and `Fail`ure and then using `isinstance` (or `match`) checks seems like a workable solution. But the second part of your answer seems incomplete. The `map` function (btw, this shadows the builtin `map` function) declares to return `Result[U]` but according to its implementation, it returns `U`. It seems that the lambda should return `Success` or `Fail` based on the condition it evaluates.

Comment: @a_guest man, i really wasn't very observant when writing this. Updated `map` (and `map2`)